# Rails: Get an Action's Controller Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

How do I get an action's controller name?

For example if I have an action called 'show', is there a way to get the name of the controller that this action 'show' belongs to?
e.g. `show.controller_name`

Comment: you have to access your action through the controller don't you? if so why don't you just directly access the name of your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, You need to know the **MVC workflow** of your application.

Secondly, you need to know that where in this **MVC workflow** are you wanting this controller name to be known for a particular action.

And third, then do:

Try this in a controller:

`self.class.to_s`

This will return the controller name for the request you made.

You can use filters in a controller to call this in turn to get the controller name.

Comment: I'm trying to generate a html table with a list of all the controllers and their corresponding actions, that's why i need to use the action to get it's controller, for example: @actions.each do |x| <tr><td>controller-name-here</td><td><%= x %></td></tr><% end %>

Comment: so how are you getting the actions in a loop. The way you are getting the actions may be wrong. You should take actions via controller names as they are the part of it or else you take them via requests using `@controller.action_name`. I mean there should be some link or source. Just `@actions.each` is like mingling of all actions at one.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller write

`@controller.controller_name` to get the name of controller

`@controller.action_name` to get the name of action

Comment: If @controller.controller_name not works then try controller.controller_name.

Comment: this won't work as I need to get the controller name from the action